# Regex expression optimization

Tags: regex, pattern-matching

User entered input value might be:

- `*` symbol with 1 character limit (no other symbols than `*`)

or

- 0-9 number and `.` (in condition of dot must not be starting or ending character) with 6 character limit

Following data is valid examples: 0.10; 010; 10; 065.34; *

I'm using following regex:

```
^([0-9]+)|([0-9]+[.]{1,1}[0-9]+)|[*]+$
```

I see that it's too long and not optimal. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this shorter regex instaed:

```
^((?=[\d.]{1,6}$)\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\*)$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qD7zJ8/5)

`(?=[\d*]{1,6}$)` is a lookahead to enforce length=6 for entire input.

Comment: `*` only 1 character allowed or 6 character numbers with dot

Comment: I tested the new regex https://regex101.com/r/qD7zJ8/3 on this example. It doesn't accept numbers without dot like: 10; 500 etc

Comment: can you re-check regex?

Comment: Oops missed out `?` after last group. It is fixed now, check